# Restringir carpeta y archivos con .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

Tengo el siguiente directorio:

```
examples
    file.php
    file2.php
helpers
    file3.php
secret
    .htaccess
    index.html
    file.json
.gitignore
index.php
README.md
```

Mi archivo *.htaccess* contiene lo siguiente:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Protect the htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

RewriteRule ^(secret/|*\.json) - [F,L,NC]

<Files "*.json">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Al entrar a la carpeta secret por la url *http://localhost/secret/* no me muestra nada (esto funciona bien) pero si entro al archivo .json dentro de dicha carpeta *http://localhost/secret/file.json* si me muestra el contenido

**¿Cómo puedo corregir mi *.htaccess* para que no muestre el contenido de dicho archivo?**

Comment: ¿Sólo quieres restringir ESE archivo o TODOS los archivos con extensión JSON?

Comment: @A.Cedano todos los archivos con la extensión .json dentro de la carpeta secret

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con esta regla te oculta todos los ficheros con la extensión indicada (no se muestran listados) y si intentas acceder a ellos por la url te da un error 403, creo que te podría servir:

```
<Files ~ "(.json)">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: podrías ampliar más tu respuesta. al vez aclarar que se debe sustituir esta linea por otra.

Answer (score 1):

con esto restringirias todos los *.json

```
<Files "*.json">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all</Files>
```

Comment: Como puedes ver en mi pregunta, ya intenté esto y no funcionó

Comment: tu linea de codigo es diferente

dice Order Allow,Deny
la mia Order Deny,Allow

Comment: Order allow,deny: hace que el servidor procese primero las reglas Allow

Order deny, allow: hace lo inverso, primero las reglas deny

Comment: No sirve de todas formas jaja

Comment: habria que ver como estan configurados los overrides, quizas ni siquiera esta tomando el .htaccess